# How to get group of currently logged in user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

How to get group of currently logged in user?
I have basic users from **django.contrib.auth** grouped into two groups: **student**, **teacher**.
I want to show the group of currently logged in user in following template:

```
{% block content %}
    <h2>
      Witaj {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}  !
    </h2>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my views.py file:

```
def login(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
    else:
        return index(request)

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def logout(request):
        logout(request)
```

Comment: if User model already have group, you can get the group from request.user.group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Template,  `{{user.groups.first.name}}`

This will print the first group in the list of all groups that the user belongs to

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it simply

1. Create a model `LoggedInUser` (have 1 field user, one2one)
2. in`login` view, add `LoggedInUser.objects.get_or_create(user=user)`
3. in `logout` view, add `LoggedInUser.objects.delete(user=request.user)`

That the simple way to do it

Comment: curious, is there any reason to make a new model when you can just use the User from the django.auth?

Comment: Yes, django best practice is to split non auth related field into another model : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model, and IMO Logged In User is more a viz feature than an auth feature

Answer (score 0):

So long as you are using the built in `User` model (havent created a custom user) then you can get access to a users group then you can use the following to get access to the users groups `request.user.groups`.

You can query what group a user is in by using something like the following:

```
if user.groups.filter(name='Student').exists():
    ...
```

If the user is not yet a member of a group they will first need to be added into a group.
In code this can be done (something) like this:

```
group = Group.objects.get(name="Student")
request.user.groups.add(group)
```